# API call with invalid database connection pointer & misuse error when updating values in table - objective c application

Tags: mysql, objective-c, sql-update

I am working on a messaging iOS application and below is the code to update a table when a new message is received for a chat:

```
- (BOOL) updateInfoForChat:(Chat*)chat {

BOOL success;
int code = 0;

if (!dbOpen && dbConnection != NULL) {
    if (sqlite3_open_v2([[DatabaseManager databasePath] UTF8String], &dbConnection, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        dbOpen = YES;
        
        const char* key = [[self getDBKey] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_key(dbConnection, key, (int)strlen(key));
        
        chat.lastMessage = [chat.lastMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%27"];
        char *errMsg;
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Chats SET "
                               "lastMessageTime = %f, lastMessageText = \"%@\", canReply = \"%@\", isArchived = \"%@\" WHERE chatRoomId = \"%@\" AND lastMessageTime <= (SELECT messageTime FROM Messages WHERE chatRoomId = \"%@\" ORDER BY messageTime DESC LIMIT 1)",
                               
                               chat.lastMsgTime, chat.lastMessage , chat.canReply ? @"True" : @"False" , chat.isArchived ? @"True" : @"False", chat.chatRoomID, chat.chatRoomID];
        
        const char *sql_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        code = (sqlite3_exec(dbConnection, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg));
        if (code == SQLITE_OK) {
            //commenting this out as this makes the logs very noisy
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"This method did not get executed with error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(dbConnection));
        }
        sqlite3_close_v2(dbConnection);
        dbOpen = NO;
    }
    
    else {
            NSLog(@"This method did not get executed with error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(dbConnection));
    }
}
return success = (code == SQLITE_OK);
```

}

Having received messages in a couple of chats, I get the errors below when application hits this code:

- API call with invalid database connection pointer
- misuse at line 133563 of [d24547a13b]
- This method did not get executed with error: bad parameter or other API misuse

Can someone suggest where the issue could be coming from?

Comment: There are two "This method did not get executed with error" possible logs, which one is it? If it's the first what's the `code` value then? If it's the last one, keep the `sqlite3_open_v2(...)` value, test it in the if, and see its value in the error output, it might give you more infos.

Comment: @Larme, thanks for your reply. I shall go test the scenarios once more and clarify!